# Plotting from .dat file in Octave - parsing problems?

Tags: plot, octave

I am running a Fortran code that is outputting several sets of data to one .dat file. I want to plot the data, which is in six columns, using Octave. For example, the data I want to plot is in the following form:

```
  0.00000     -0.74801     -1.28157     -0.83853     -0.48516      1.63291
  0.50000     -0.77323     -1.29113     -0.05049      0.41035      1.43455
  1.00000     -0.77395     -0.92811      0.53030      0.97057      0.84562
  1.50000     -0.53535     -0.39600      0.77706      1.08468      0.14751
  2.00000     -0.11992      0.09400      0.70391      0.82753     -0.39832
  2.50000      0.13110      0.40199      0.42843      0.39346     -0.65142
  3.00000      0.18444      0.49287      0.09997     -0.01108     -0.62348
  3.50000      0.21139      0.41749     -0.16809     -0.26034     -0.43447
  4.00000      0.06769      0.26052     -0.33161     -0.34466     -0.22600
  4.50000     -0.11022      0.08786     -0.40536     -0.33917     -0.08197
  5.00000     -0.30134     -0.07872     -0.42390     -0.33216      0.00230
```

I'm trying to plot column 2 against column 1 (this is just a sample of the data), and then eventually the rest of the columns against column 1. At the moment, my Octave script looks like:

This script reads in values of the free surface from data file and plots the values against time

```
%Load text file
data = 'filename.dat';
m = dlmread(data);
t = m(:,2);
eta = m(:,3);
plot(t,eta);
title('Free surface eta(t) vs time');
xlabel('Time (s)');
ylabel('Location of free surface');
grid on
```

However, my plot is blank. If i scroll through the .dat file, it tells me that the values in what looks like the first column are in columns 6-14 and the values for 'column 2' are actually in columns 19-27. Could this be why the plot is blank? Maybe it isn't seeing them as numbers in 'column 1' against 'column 2'? Anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Before asking about a `plot(t, eta)` problem, it is better to inspect `t` and `eta` first. This would yield a better question like "why is a column full of zeroes with `dlmread`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the line  m = dlmread(data, separator)

If you specify delimiters as a single space like you show on here, the result is an 11 x 32 matrix.  Some of the columns in filename.dat have 5 spaces between them, some have 6, depending on the negative sign.  It is inserting zeroes between all of the spaces.  You are getting blank plots because you are plotting a column of zeros vs a column of zeros.

According to the octave documentation, dlmread will define it's own delimiters if one isn't provided.
My suggestion is to modify the octave script like this:

```
m = dlmread(data); % creates an 11 x 6 matrix
```

I copied and pasted your data from above.  If there are spaces before column 1 in your data file, then it will create an 11 x 7 matrix with column 1 as all zeros.  Make sure you use t = m(:,2) and eta = m(:,3) if you have spaces before the first column.

Comment: Thanks! I got a plot now but it's definitely not the shape I expected (some sort of sine wave was what it should look like... It seems to be reading my first column incorrectly (at first glance the y values look correct) but the x-axis is only going from -6 to 6 and the y axis is from -4 to 4 (the y axis should be random but in my data I have values greater than 4).... I don't see where the values are coming from now? Do you have any suggestions? It should be a simple enough random wave against time plot... right now I have a big squiggle

Comment: When I run the code using m = dlmread(data), I get t values of 0-5 in .5 increments, and eta values equivalent to the column 2 from the data you have above.  Does your data file contain the same data as above?  To set the limits, use axis ([x_lo x_hi y_lo y_hi]), for example, axis ([0, 5, -1, 1])

Comment: Yeah I have those same values... I'll try setting the axis. I'm guessing that's part of the dlmread command? (I think I read that but I dont' have it in front of me  now)

Comment: axis is not part of the dlmread.  axis is it's own function to be run right after plot.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll give that a try. Although I wonder if I can show you the plot somehow as it's not just the limits that are the problem?

Comment: Unless it goes against so policies (?) I don't see why you can't use a photosharing link like uploadpie: http://uploadpie.com/F8MAA

Comment: ok here's mine: http://uploadpie.com/sb52O !! I have no idea why it looks like this, I am running exactly the code I have put in with those values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62417/discussion-between-alex-b-and-user3460758).